# Rewrite Wishlist Controller (IndexController)

Tags: magento-enterprise

I'm trying to rewrite a controller function but somehow I have somewhere an error:

In `config.xml`:

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Bm_SpamProtect before="Mage_Wishlist_IndexController">
                            Bm_SpamProtect
                        </Bm_SpamProtect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Start of my `IndexController.php` in my Module:

```
<?php

    require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Wishlist').DS.'IndexController.php';


    class Bm_SpamProtect_IndexController extends Mage_Wishlist_IndexController {

....

     }
```

However, the function is still returning the original code instead of my one. Wheres the error?

Comment: I have the same error and the same code.. Do you succeed to resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml`, `before="Mage_Wishlist_IndexController"` should be `before="Mage_Wishlist"`

Comment: Ah, sure... However, it still returns the wrong code. :(